# returning byte array reference from android java to csharp unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

byte[] bytes = Call("getBytes") ;  where getBytes function returns a byte[].

above function is called to fetch image rgb data in csharp. Returned byte[] is deep copied into the bytes array.

Since return byte array is large, deep copying adds more time.

how to make bytes array in csharp to hold only reference of java byte[]?

```
public class TestUtil : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static string TAG = "--------TestUtil------------> ";

    private static AndroidJavaObject pluginClass;    
    public static List<byte[]> rgbList = new List<byte[]>();

    void Start()
    {


        Debug.Log(TAG + "start called");

        //mainDataArray = new byte[1280*720*4];
        Debug.Log(TAG + "creating java object");

        initializePlayer();

    }

    public void initializePlayer()
    {
        // StreamHandler is the Javaclass. here i am creating a object StreamHandler
        pluginClass = new AndroidJavaObject("com.test.android.decoder.StreamHandler");

       // using this code to get the context
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        // setting context StreamHandler object
        pluginClass.Call("setActivity", activity);

        // setting the interface object, where java class will call the respective function
        pluginClass.Call("setOnDecodeListener", new AndroidPluginCallback());       

        // initializing the player
        pluginClass.Call("init", ipAddress, port, outWidth, outHeight);

        Debug.Log(TAG + " Initialization done");
    }

    public void quitApplication(string sid)
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape)) {
            Debug.Log(TAG + "Escape");
            quitApplication(sId);
        }        
    }

    int count;
    private void LateUpdate()
    {



            if (0 != rgbList.Count) {
                // here i am updating the rgb texture to Quad gameobject
        }

    }

    class AndroidPluginCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
    {
        public AndroidPluginCallback() : base("com.test.android.OnDecodeListener") { }

        public void success(byte[] videoPath)
        {            
        }

        public void onFrameAvailable()
        {

            // Called when java code successfully generate RGBA data

            long startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

            // Need to call "getBytes()" to get the RGBA frame. 
            //Note: generally if you call same function from another java class it do shallow copy to byte[] object 
            // but in this case it is doing deep copy or i am not sure whats going on.

            byte[] rawBytes = pluginClass.Call<byte[]>("getBytes"); // width and height of frame is 1088x1088

            rgbList.Add(rawBytes);

            long diff = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() - startTime;
            Debug.Log(TAG + "Entered into onFrameAvailable callback. time taken to copy to rawbytes: " + diff); // diff is 14ms on average. Not sure why.
        }

        public void fail(string errorMessage)
        {
            Debug.Log(TAG + "ENTER callback onError: " + errorMessage);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We need to know more about exactly what `Call("getBytes")` does. Please post enough code to reproduce your problem statement.

Comment: I have image data converted to rgba format, saved in byte[]. I'm calling getBytes() function from unity.    public void getByted(){ return rgbBug;}

Comment: if you're doing `return rgbBug` that's returning the reference by value, so it shouldn't be a deep copy...

Comment: I double checked, unity s doing deep copy. I want to avoid this

Comment: There's really not enough information here to replicate your problem. Please add more information so we can reproduce the problem statement by adding a [mre] to the question.

Comment: @Ruzihm sorry for late response. I updated the question, kindly check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AndroidJavaObject` uses the JNI (Java Native Interface) to marshal data to and from Java land. Depending on how Java stores the arrays in memory, the JNI may need to do a deep copy to form an array that C# would understand, such as if the JVM originally stored the array in non-contiguous blocks.

Here's [IBM's description](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/index.html):

> JNI provides a clean interface between Java code and native code. To maintain this separation, arrays are passed as opaque handles, and native code must call back to the JVM in order to manipulate array elements using set and get calls. **The Java specification leaves it up to the JVM implementation whether these calls provide direct access to the arrays or return a copy of the array. For example, the JVM might return a copy when it has optimized arrays in a way that does not store them contiguously.**
>
> These calls, then, might cause copying of the elements being manipulated. For example, if you call GetLongArrayElements() on an array with 1,000 elements, you might cause the allocation and copy of at least 8,000 bytes (1,000 elements * 8 bytes for each long). When you then update the array's contents with ReleaseLongArrayElements(), another copy of 8,000 bytes might be required to update the array. Even when you use the newer GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(), the specification still permits the JVM to make copies of the full array.

So basically, try to avoid marshalling arrays across the JNI (such as with `AndroidJavaObject` as much as possible, because it's not up to the C# on whether the JNI makes a deep copy or not.